# touchpad turning circles into squares

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, synaptics

I've got a Lenovo T450s that I'm running LUbuntu 18.04 on.  I've got the Synaptics driver and am using [Touchpad-Indicator](https://github.com/atareao/Touchpad-Indicator) for touchpad control.

I have noticed that the touchpad seems very jerky at times, and when I experimented with it I discovered it is only jerky when I am trying to make arcing or circular motions, for instance when trying to make the motion of signing my name.

In the image below, I watched the touchpad to make my finger move in as close to a circle as possible:

[image]

As you can see, instead of being a circle, the cursor wanted to move in straight lines and only change directions at certain intervals.

I tried again, this time to draw a quick circle:

[image]

Instead of a circle it is looking more and more like a square with rounded corners!

I tried disabling natural scrolling and circular scrolling under Touchpad Indicator -> Preferences -> Touchpad configuration, but it made no difference.

How can I make the touchpad behave properly? It's practically useless like this!

Comment: i've tried to install this indicator, it broke all my settings, circles became more ugly, click on touch doesn't work anymore. feels like it's cow sh*
best way is
`sudo apt-get purge touchpad-indicator && sudo reboot`

Comment: @VasiliiSuricov Unfortunately after I do this, I again have the issue of the touchpad accidentally being hit when I am typing.

Comment: `$ synclient -l` to see all settings.
and for me works this  
`$ cat /etc/rc.local  
#!/bin/sh -e  
synclient FingerHigh=40  
synclient FingerLow=35  
synclient VertScrollDelta=180  
synclient HorizScrollDelta=180  
synclient MinSpeed=0.7  
synclient MaxSpeed=1.7  
synclient AccelFactor=0.03  
synclient HorizHysteresis=14  
synclient VertHysteresis=14`

Comment: See `Palm*` section

Comment: I have the exact same problem on my HP Elitebook. Both broblems - touchpad not disabling while typing correctly (even though it's configured) and touchpad only moving in 90 degree angles. It's really unusable and I don't know how to solve it. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Especially during fine precision movement.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was finally to run:

```
$ synclient HorizHysteresis=0
$ synclient VertHysteresis=0
```

Now my touchpad can move the cursor diagonally and in tight circles (Xubuntu, HP Elitebook).